# NGiNX single worker process-Flow

Tags: nginx, benchmarking

I am using a single worker process and master_process off in nginx.conf. 
Now as per my understanding, the flow of operation would be something like:
NGiNX master process created which will spawn a single worker_process using fork and then master process gets killed.
Is that correct ?

If yes then is it possible to avoid forking. 
Pthreads is just now been introduced as a testing feature in NGiNX, so I don't want to use it. Is there any other way also to avoid fork?

Comment: What do you try to do?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:When master_process is set to off, then master process does not fork any child processes and all requests are processed by the master process.